# arrange data into special manner (3 in a row) with a show n fields button

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to display my data coming from sql db to front end. I want it to be displayed in some special manner.

Lets assume I have 8 element in total. I want to display only 3 data field at first in a row, and below that a message saying 'show remaining 5'. 
Once someone click that another three should load and below a message would show 'show remaining 1'.

I am not asking for a ..read more type option. I want to display remaining data into segments, but not all at once. If anyone can guide me, what can I use or if there is any useful plugin, I am already grateful.

Thanks in advance for anyone who put some effort.

Comment: Have you even tried it yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like something that would be done by JavaScript. This means building the whole table right away, but hiding all but the top 3 rows. Then hook a function to the "Show three more" button, that displays three more rows (until all is shown).

[jQuery](https://jquery.com/) is a JavaScript library that is easy to get into and would help you get this kind of functionality going, but it is of course entirely possible to do without it.

If you are entirely new to web development with php, sql, html, and javascript I suggest looking at basic tutorials on how to accomplish the basics first, such as fetching data from a db, displaying that in html and how to modify the DOM with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information, but im gonna answer according to what i understood.
First you need to put the data in a table using `<table><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table>`. 
Then you can hide the other 5 data fields using css, you can use `visibility: hidden` or `display:none`.

Then you can display a message using `bootstrap alert class` thats says `5 other fields remaining`.